# Roots of cubic equation by Vieta's formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got the roots for the cubic equation:
$a+b+c=-p, a b + b c + c a=0, a b c =-q.$
Then I calculate $a^2+b^2+c^2=p^2$
via $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2 (a b + b c + c a).$
My goal is to calculate
$a^3 c + b^3 a+ c^3 b$
in terms of $a+b+c, a b + b c + c a, a b c ,$ but I don't know any related formula. Thank you

Comment: $a^3c+b^3a+c^3b$ and $a^3b+b^3c+c^3a$ will be the roots of a quadratic equation whose coefficients are symmetric functions of $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: I can't understand your comment

Comment: To write down your polynomial will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

let a,b,c be the roots of this equation. $a+b+c=-p, a b + b c + c a=0, a b c =-q.$
then the equation is $$x^3+px^2+q=0$$

divide by $x\implies x^2+px+\frac{q}{x}=0 $

$a,b,c$ are roots, substituting it  in this equation.we get
$$a^2c+pac+\frac{qc}{a}=0 $$
$$b^2a+pba+\frac{qa}{b}=0 $$

$$c^2b+pbc+\frac{bq}{c}=0 $$

add all equations we can find $a^2c+b^2a+c^2b$

$a,b,c$ are roots, substituting it  in this equation.we get

$$a^3+pa^2+q=0 \implies a^3c+pa^2c+qc=0$$
$$b^3+pb^2+q=0 \implies b^3a+pb^2a+qa=0$$
$$c^3+pc^2+q=0 \implies c^3b+pc^2b+qb=0$$

and add all equations we get,
$$[a^3 c + b^3 a+ c^3 b]+p[a^2c+b^2a+c^2b]+q[a+b+c]=0$$

$$[a^3 c + b^3 a+ c^3 b]+p[a^2c+b^2a+c^2b]-pq=0$$

$$[a^3 c + b^3 a+ c^3 b]=pq-p[a^2c+b^2a+c^2b]$$

substituting value of $a^2c+b^2a+c^2b$ in above equation can get $[a^3 c + b^3 a+ c^3 b]$